# Wordpress. Показ разных виджетов в зависимости от геолокации заходящего клиента

Tags: wordpress, геолокация

Какие есть способы реализации отображения разных виджетов в зависимости от геолокации пользователя?
Как WP может определить откуда идет аудитория? Можно плагином, или php/js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В репозитории есть ряд плагинов на эту тему. Один из них - [Geolocation IP Detection](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/geoip-detect/).